# I have a method where i have taken the rowcount of 10 records on page load and 15 records after changing the page no to 15 question how to validate

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have a method where i have taken the rowcount of 10 records on page load and 15 records after changing the page no to 15 question here is how to validate by creating a Assert method seperatly in order to validate the count

Below is my method:

```
    public void pagenation()
{

    List<WebElement> noofrowbefore = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/p"));
    int beforecount = noofrowbefore.size();
    for(int i=0;i<noofrowbefore.size();i++)
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,2500)");

    elementInteraction.onClick(pagedropdown);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pagenumberselection));
    elementInteraction.onClick(pagenumberselection);
  //after selecting  the pagenumber need to validate the number of records in the grid
    List<WebElement> noofrowAfter = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/p"));
    int aftercount = noofrowAfter.size();
}
```

Any inputs..

Comment: Hi. Pardon if it sounds rude, but the question is difficult to understand grammarly. I would suggest explaining succinctly your context, your goal, what you tried to do, what your results were, and what are your questions - each part in one paragraph/sentence and referencing your code's elements.

Comment: Agree but got a solution to this thanks @JoãoFarias

Answer (score 0):

To validate the count of records before and after changing the page number, you can create a separate Assert method. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to include the Assert method:

```
import org.testng.Assert;

public void pagination() {
    List<WebElement> noOfRowsBefore = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/p"));
    int beforeCount = noOfRowsBefore.size();

    // Scroll down the page
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,2500)");

    elementInteraction.onClick(pagedropdown);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pagenumberselection));
    elementInteraction.onClick(pagenumberselection);

    // Wait for the page to load with new records
    // Add necessary wait condition here if required

    List<WebElement> noOfRowsAfter = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/p"));
    int afterCount = noOfRowsAfter.size();

    // Assertion
    Assert.assertEquals(afterCount, beforeCount + 5, "Number of records is not as expected after changing the page number.");
}
```

In this example, I have used the `assertEquals` method from TestNG's Assert class to compare the count of records before and after changing the page number. The expected count after changing the page number is `beforeCount + 5`, assuming each page displays 5 records.

You can customize the assertion according to your specific requirement. If the count doesn't match, the assertion will throw an assertion error with the provided message.